# Find $P[X-Y=1]$ given $X,Y \sim Bin(20, 1/5)$

Tags: probability, binomial-distribution, multinomial-distribution

> You, your parents, your sister, go to visit grandma for her birthday. Grandma made a cake for the party. If she puts $20$ raisins in the cake at random in the cake, and she divides the cake into $5$ equal pieces, what's the probability that you get one more than than your sister?

Let X be the number of raisins you have and Y be the number of raisins she has.

$X,Y \sim Bin(20, 1/5)$

Either $P[X-Y = 1]$ or $P[X-Y \neq 1]$.

$P[X-Y > 1] + P[X-Y=1]+ P[X-Y<1]=1$.

Comment: No, we're not even talking about the same problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's true that $X, Y$ are each individually binomially distributed... but I don't think that's quite as helpful as you want it to be, because $X$ and $Y$ are quite dependent on one another. (Example: if you know that $X = 15$, then this forces $Y \leq 5$.)

I'd consider some cases separately and compute the probability of each case directly:

- You get 1 raisin and your sister gets 0.
- You get 2 raisins and your sister gets 1.
- You get 3 raisins and your sister gets 2.
  $$\vdots$$
- You get 10 raisins and your sister gets 9. (This is the last case you have to consider -- why?)

To compute any one of these, we can use a [multinomial distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_distribution#Example). For instance, the probability that you get 3 raisins and your sister gets 2 (hence, 15 go to the unused portion of the cake) is
$$\binom{20}{3, 2, 15}(1/5)^3 \cdot (1/5)^2 \cdot (3/5)^{15} = \left( \frac{20!}{3! \cdot 2! \cdot 15!} \right) (1/5)^3 \cdot (1/5)^2 \cdot (3/5)^{15}$$
which can be simplified, of course. You then have $10$ such terms which represent disjoint events, and whose union is the event that you want, so you can add their probabilities to get your answer.

(It's possible that there's a simpler way to do this, but this was the simplest one I could think of right now.)

Comment: Does hypergeometric distribution also work?

Comment: Not in a way that I can see. A hypergeometric distribution requires a sample (of fixed size $n$) taken without replacement from a larger population. What would that sample be, here?

Comment: $n=20$ is that fixed n.

Comment: Then you're saying: "Take a sample of $n= 20$ (blank) without replacement from a larger collection of (blank)." Note that (blank) must be filled in the same way in both cases; I can't think of a sensible way to do that in this problem. At the very least, "raisins" certainly does not fill in that blank.